# Add Item to Sharepoint list with Power Automate Desktop

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list

Using Power Automate (cloud flows) is easy add an item to a SharePoint list. However, I haven't found a good built in solution to using Power Automate Desktop (PAD) to add an item to a SharePoint list.

The goal is to keep record of all the PAD desktop flows run for keeping record of time savings, audit etc. for multiple groups. Currently the solution is adding a line to a Excel SharePoint file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but if you have PAD adding a line to an excel file that's on SP, simply set up a new cloud flow that's triggered by the new row in that file, then an action that adds an item to the SP list with the dynamic content from the excel.

It's a step more than ideal, but it should all be background processing... so it shouldn't be much of an issue.